# How Do I Add A Where Condition Dynamically In JPA/DB2

Tags: java, jpa, db2

Currently I have a java application that is querying a DB2 10.5 database and uses JPA 2.0 as the wrapper.  I have a working query that works well to get data I need. However, I have a need for a second query that is exactly the same as the first one except for adding a dynamic parameter.  They queries are big enough (and there are several similar ones) that it seems like a ton of duplication to list out the same query essentially twice but have one that contains an extra where condition and one that doesn't Let me try to give my example:

In my orm.xml (we tend to use named-query and named-native-query) I have the following named-query:

```
select dates
       from DateTable dates, Product p
       where dates.id = p.id
       and ... <multiple conditions etc>
```

My second query will be something exactly the same as the above, except
will take a dynamic argument from the code:

```
select dates
      from DateTable, Product p
      where dates.id = p.id
      and p.id = :someDynamicIdHere
      and ... <multiple conditions etc>
```

I would like to combine them into one orm.xml definition that JPA can understand. To be clear I want to add the extra where condition "and p.id = :someDynamicIdHere" when someDynamicIdHere is not null. I have tried CASE/WHEN/THEN/END but my use in the past has only been for column manipulation and not for updating a where clause on the fly. Is this possible and if so what is the syntax? Thanks for any help! 
-Doug

Comment: If you want to dynamically generate a query, just do it. Java can do that just fine. XML can't, however. So don't put them in orm.xml, and put them in the Java code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use criteria API:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
    Root<Entity> r = cq.from(Entity.class);

    List<Predicate> p = new ArrayList<>();

    //conditionally create zero or more conditions
    Predicate condition= cb.equal(r.get("fieldName"), user.getId());
    p.add(condition);

    if(Collections.isNotEmpty(p)){
         Predicate[] pArray = p.toArray(new Predicate[]{});
         Predicate predicate = cb.and(pArray);
         cq.where(predicate);
    }
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get("fieldName")));

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```